# What should our custom off-topic reasons be?

Tags: discussion, scope, close-reasons

Recently Stack Exchange rolled out a massive change to the way [questions are closed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/?cb=1).  With those changes, we now have the opportunity to define more closely why a question is off topic.  The Community Manager Team thoughtfully provided us with these reasons:

- Questions without a specific Bible passage are off-topic as we cannot apply hermeneutical methods to text if there is no text.
- Questions regarding doctrinal interpretations are off-topic, but can be asked on [Christianity Stack Exchange](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/about) or [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/about).

Do these reasons look good?  Should they be re-worded?  Do we need to use our [third reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185097/1438)?

Answer (score 2):

I would start with an option for questions that have nothing to do with hermeneutics:

- Questions that do not pertain to hermeneutics (or exegesis) are off-topic. Questions about religion, doctrine, and church history may be asked on Christianity.SE or Mi Yodeya.SE.

This is essentially a rework of Option 2 from the OP, but broadened to cover *any* non-hermeneutics question. This could be used for questions about religion, doctrine, church history, ANE history, philosophy, etc.

---

Given that this site is specifically devoted to **Biblical** hermeneutics and exegesis, I would add the following:

- Questions that pertain to the interpretation of extra-Biblical texts are off topic, as this site is devoted to Biblical hermeneutics.

This option could be used for questions about the interpretation of extra-Biblical texts, such as the writings of Josephus or the extra-Biblical community documents found at Qumran. It could also be used for general questions about languages, communication, etc.

---

Once we've curbed questions that have nothing to do with Biblical hermeneutics, we could get more precise with our other reason for closing. Since we require exegesis questions to specify a passage, I would add the following as a third option:

- Questions about exegesis that do not specify a text are off-topic, as we cannot perform exegesis on a text if there is no text.

This is essentially Option 1 from the OP reworded with GoneQuiet's suggestion, and pruned under the assumption of the other two options I proposed.